# How to see res/drawable-nodpi/ folder in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I got an error in `res/drawable-nodpi-v4/flag_dominican_republic.png` collided.

I don't know how to see that folder in Android Studio. Please help me

[image: Image that shows error during build]

Comment: Chane your drawable-nodpi-v4 to drawable-nodpi , If you want to see this folder change project view to "Project" (top - right where it is labeled Android by default)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Build > Clean Project` or `Build > Rebuild Project` ?

Answer (score 0):

it looks that you have another resource with that name, try renaming the drawable then `Build > Clean Project` and `Build > Rebuild Project`